# Constructing an object and then autowiring in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a servlet that gets some parameters and from those I construct another object(responseObject). This response object is accessed in a lot of classes elsewhere so it needs to be autowired in those classes.

The other classes can add content into the responseObject(essentially modify the object).

So summing up the desired features are :

- A new responseObject for every new servlet request
- This responseObject will first be constructed inside the servlet and the same must be available for access in other classes
- The other classes that access this object must be able to add/change content in this object which will remain consistent.

I am wondering if such a thing is possible in Spring.

I tried prototype and request scopes but I ran into errors.
The main issue is that the object needs to be modified by other classes and needs to have those changes while the request is still being served.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not what autowiring is used for. What you want to do is simply pass the response object to the classes/methods that need it.

A word of advise:
It is better to not let request and response objects wander too much through your codebase. You want to limit their use as much as possible to the places where they are actually needed (i.e. servlets). The servlet may need some data from several places to produce a reponse. That's fine. Get the data and produce the response. It is better to pass the data to where the response is than to pass the reponse to where the data is. Same for the request object, but the other way around. The underlying principle is that it is usually best to decouple input from output.

Comment: I get it. That is one solution.Is it possible to construct a bean after I get the HTTPrequest and then the other classes get the same?

Comment: Yes, simply pass the bean around via parameters after you've created it. Autowiring is meant for the instantation of singletons or the creation of new beans without an explicit factory, not for passing instances of objects around.